# Equation of Tangent and Normal Lines to a Certain Curve

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I stumbled upon this question on a book and tried to solve it myself. It goes like this:

Find the equation of the tangent and the normal to the following curves at the point indicated:

$ x= t^2 -2t$, $y= t^3 - 3t; $  $t= 2$

My work:

This is a parametric equation, so I got to find its rectangular equation.

The problem is: It's difficult for me to get its rectangular equation because I can't isolate the $x's $ from $t's$ and the $y's $ from $t's$

I got the slope $m = \frac{9}{2}$ from getting the derivative of the given parametric equation.

My question is how do you get the tangent and the normal lines to the parametric equation above?

Comment: If you have found the slope, just plug in the given value for $t$ to get a point, which allows you to find the line.

Comment: Another note: you don't need to find the rectangular form to get the derivative; use the identity $\frac {dy}{dx} = \frac{\frac{dy}{dt}}{ \frac{dx}{dt}}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just find the slope $m$ for the tamgent. Use this slope value to get the slope of the normal $-\frac{1}{m}$. Now use the formula,
$$y-y(t_0)=(\text{slope})(x-x(t_0))$$
to find the equations of the tangent and the normal at any time $t_0$.